# How to do MySQL IN clauses using Zend DB?

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, escaping, prepared-statement

I'm trying to fetch rows that are in an array of integers that I have using Zend Framework 1.11.

```
$this->dbSelect
         ->from($table_prefix . 'product_link')
         ->joinLeft($table_prefix . 'product_link_name', $table_prefix . 'product_link.product_link_name_ref_id = ' . $table_prefix . 'product_link_name.product_link_name_id')
         ->where('product_ref_id IN (?)', implode(', ', $product_ids));
```

When I use the `__toString()` method of `$this->dbSelect`, I get

```
SELECT `phc_distrib_product_link`.*,
     `phc_distrib_product_link_name`.* 
FROM `phc_distrib_product_link` 
LEFT JOIN `phc_distrib_product_link_name` 
ON phc_distrib_product_link.product_link_name_ref_id = phc_distrib_product_link_name.product_link_name_id 
WHERE (product_ref_id IN ('10, 12'))
```

This only returns rows satisfying the condition where product_ref_id = 10.
How can I get the IN clause to be

```
product_ref_id IN ('10', '12')
```

or

```
product_ref_id IN (10, 12)
```

using Zend DB prepared statements so I can fetch all rows contained inside the product id array?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Don't implode the array, just pass it:

```
->where('product_ref_id IN (?)', $product_ids);
```

Comment: So right, thank you!  You answered so fast I can't accept the answer yet, but I will when I am allowed to!

Answer (score 1):

It is worth mentioned that there is 2 ways to use WHERE IN clausule in Zend_Db_Select:

1. We can pass array as second parameter:

   `$select->where("column_value IN (?)", $array_of_values)`
2. Or we can simply implode array to get values as string:

   `$select->where("column_value IN (" . implode(',', $array_of_values) . ")")`

Comment: Second method is not safe at all if `$array_of_values` is not an array of integers!
Just imagine using this in a delete() while `$array_of_values` contains:
array("column_value"). This will result in:
`DELETE FROM table_name WHERE column_value IN (column_value)`
which will remove everything!

Answer (score 0):

```
->where('country_id IN (?)', $country_ids);
```